# go test ./... running out of memory

Tags: go, out-of-memory

I'm running `go test ./...` on our build system and it is taking up a lot of memory, sometimes up to 4Gb on one of our systems. Is there a way to have `go test` be less resource consuming?

Edit: To give more context we run tests in a docker image. We have 30 directories, and for every directory we create a docker image and run tests within it. We run `make -j4 test_each_all_directories`.
Our machine has 15Gb of ram, and each directory takes <2Gb (except one that takes 4Gb).

I was looking into a way to "force" go test to use 3Gb max of memory, or have more explanation of what goes wrong (things don't add up, 15Gb of ram is way more than 4+2+2+2 at most)

Comment: 1) you're doing something wrong 2) you actually have no enough memory

Comment: Is it actually failing during test execution, or is building all the packages what's failing?

Comment: This is happening during test execution. Build works fine. Most of the times test pass, but it looks like we are just around the memory limit so sometimes they fail, and I was investigating how to improve this. Adding more context in the question

Comment: You cannot limit the amount of RAM a Go program will use (and `go test` just builds and runs a GO program). If your tests actually _use_ that much RAM you cannot start that many tests runs in parallel. You might want to try reducing the GOGC env variable to e.g. 50: `GOGC=50 go test`.

Answer (score 1):

Your tests might take significantly longer to run, but have you tried running your tests in sequence? From `go help build`

```
-p n
                the number of programs, such as build commands or
                test binaries, that can be run in parallel.
                The default is the number of CPUs available.
```

By default, Go will run several test packages in parallel if possible. To make sure tests spanning multiple packages are run in sequence, run your test command with `-p 1`. Your test command would become:

```
go test ./... -p 1
```

Comment: Just to clarify, `-p` is a build flag, and it changes how many packages are _compiled_ concurrently. The tests are always run in series (but this very well may be the problem).